# What the difference between offset and no. of entries in a page?

Tags: operating-system, paging

Suppose that a machine has 38-bit virtual addresses and 32-bit physical addresses.

(b) With a two-level page table, 16-KB pages, and 4-byte entries, how many bits should be allocated for the top-level page table field and how many for the next level page table field? Explain.

And here's the answer:

The offset field requires 14 bits to address 16 KB. That leaves 24 bits for the page fields. Since each entry is 4 bytes, **one page can hold 16KB / 4 byte = 2^12**
page table entries and **therefore requires 12 bits to index one page**. So allocating 12 bits for each
of the page fields will address all 2^38 bytes.

---

I don't quite understand if we have offset 14 bit which is used to address within the page, then what is **one page can hold 16KB / 4 byte = 2^12** ? Another offset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer original question:
No, it is not a second offset, it is just used as index inside in the second-level page table. First 12 bits act as index to the entry in the first level, second 12 bits act as index inside the secondary page table.

---

- 38 bit virtual addresses
- 16KB page size
- 32 bit physical addresses

We can conclude:

1. main memory size is **2^32** = **4GB**.
2. log2(16K) = 14, **14 bits** for **offset**.
3. Page entry is **4 bytes**
4. 38-14 = **24 bits** to reference page
5. 2^24 different virtual pages
6. 2^18 different physical frames

Now assume we want to allocate space for a page table, if we allocate it a page which is `16KB`, how many entries will it have ? **16K/4** = **4K entries**.

```
PAGE:
0x000   entry 1
0x001    
0x002    
0x003          
-----------------
0x004   entry 2
0x005
0x006    
0x007
------------------
.       entry 3
.
.
. 
------------------
0xFFC   entry 4096 (NOTE! 4K = 4096 as its 2^12)
0xFFD
0xFFE
0xFFF
------------------
```

Now if we divide the 24 bits for pages in half, 12 bits for first level page and 12 bits for second level page. How many pages can we address ?

First level has `2^12` different pages, where each entry points to a second level page table. Second level page table also has 2^12 entries, each entry points to a frame which its size is 16KB.

```
(2^12)*(2^12)*(2^14) = 2^38
```

With this 2-level page tables you can address 2^38 virtual addresses.

Comment: @Cubancoffee I think I missclicked or had a mistake... it should be `2^12*2^12*2^14 = 2^38`. You have first level which has 2^12 entries, second level also has 2^12 entries. multiply those by the page size.